# Bar buttons: Yellowish-Brown back light

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-930, buttons

Just got my Nokia Lumia 930 today and I realized 3 things:

1. Lock button a little bit loose
2. Bar buttons with back light a little darker (it should be bright white)
3. Chinese manual (maybe chinese version of the phone)

Should I be scared or return the phone?

Someone with the same behavior in theirs?

Comment: Did you buy this from an authorised reseller in your country?

Comment: It was bought in a online store of my country and the seller guy has nice reputation in the site (is like a Latin American Amazon). The cellphone is legit, I have checked some of the codes you can dial to see if the phone is legit and everything but the buttons are OK.